# Asynchronous dispatch in a called method

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I am trying to complete a long calculation with a determinate progress bar.  This is working fine with the below code.  However, in the method which calls `scan`, it immediately moves on to `scoreWithEquation` before `scan` has finished updating the `StoredLibrary` object.  I've tried all the different methods for waiting for the dispatch queues to finish, but they all end up hanging the UI.  Do I need to be using a callback?  I've looked into this solution, but I don't understand how to pass all the arguments and return variables back and forth.

```
-(void) scan{
if (!_sheet){
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"ProgressSheet" owner: self];
}
[NSApp beginSheet: _sheet
   modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate]window]
    modalDelegate: self
   didEndSelector: NULL
      contextInfo: nil];

[_sheet makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

[_progressBar setIndeterminate:YES];
[_progressBar setMinValue:0];
[_progressBar startAnimation:self];

__block NSMutableArray *tempTracks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//do stuff

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        //do stuff
        [_progressBar setDoubleValue:0.f];
        [_progressBar setMaxValue:[listTracks count]];
        [_progressBar setIndeterminate:NO];

        for (iTunesTrack *listTrack in listTracks) {
            //do stuff to tempTracks
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [_progressBar incrementBy:1];
            }); 
        }
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_progressBar setIndeterminate:YES];
        [NSApp endSheet:self.sheet];
        [self.sheet orderOut:self];
        self.listTracks = tempTracks;
    });
});
}
```

Below is the code which calls `scan`:

```
- (IBAction)evaluate:(id)sender {
        if (self.storedLibrary == nil){
            self.storedLibrary = [[StoredLibrary alloc] init];
            [self.storedLibrary scan];
        }
self.tableTracks = [self.storedLibrary scoreWithequation:[_scoringEquation stringValue]
                                               sortOrder:[_sortOrder titleOfSelectedItem]                                                                                                   
                                              trackLimit:[_trackLimit integerValue]];
}
```

I would like to keep `scan` and `scoreWithEquation` as separate methods, as they are called elsewhere separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use dispatch_async the block dispatched will not block the current thread, and the execution will continue immediatly.

In your case, when you call scan, you do some stuff and then call dispatch_async to do other stuff. everything in the dispatch block will not be executed in this run loop and  [self.storedLibrary scan] returns so scoreWithequation will be executed immediatly.

If you want to block the current thread (the thread on which the dispatch call is executed) you need to use dispatch_sync.

if you want to execute scoreWithequation after scan, you can create a serial_queue, and dispatch_async both scan and then scoreWithequation to the custom serial_queue. Doing so the execution will not block the current thread, and they will be executed in serie.

check "creating serial dispatch queue" ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html )

or retaining a completion block to execute scoreWithequation as a callback is also a possibility.

Comment: I have actually tried this, but it was not working.  The instance variable that `scan` is updating (`listTracks`) does not seem to be updated when `scoreWithEquation` is called.  I was thinking that perhaps this is because the dispatch is sent before the instance variable is updated.

Comment: in you code scoreWithEquation is called before "//do stuff to tempTracks" in scan is executed. if you dispatch to a serial queue, they are executed in serie. you have to dispatch async scoreWithequation to the same serial queue of "scan"

Comment: I just tried it again and figured out what the problem was.  Moving `self.listTracks = tempTracks;` outside of the ` dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` block seemed to be the problem.  If it was inside, it was updated after `scoreWithEquation` was called.